# UIPanGestureRecognizer interception on SideMenu and UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I have leftMenu appears when swipe to right, and I want my tab changes when swipe to left whole page.

Their UIPanGestureRecognizer intercepts, I have tried disabling bouncing of UIScrollView of UIPageViewController, tried requireGestureRecognizerToFail:

But I could not make it both of them works. What I want is when it is swiped to to right side menu appears. When it is swiped to left if sidemenu is open it will close, if not, page will change.

My sample code is as follows;

```
 for(UIScrollView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews)
 {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
       UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;

       AppDelegate *appDel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

       UIPanGestureRecognizer* panGestureRecognizer = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer;
       [panGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
       [panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:appDel.slidingViewController.panGesture];
    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work (warning: untested!)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panRecognized:)];
    panRecognizer.delegate = self;

    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers)
        [recognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panRecognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recogniser
{
    if (self.leftMenuShowing)
        return YES;
    else
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = (id)recognizer;
        CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
        return (translation.x > 0);
    }
}

- (void)panRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer)
{
    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        // if pan is to left, move leftMenu offscreen
        // if pan is to right, move leftMenu onscreen
    }
    else
    {
        // if leftMenu is mostly onscreen, animate completely onscreen
        // if leftMenu is mostly offscreen, animate completely offscreen
    }
}
```